# Statistical Analysis of the sum of the highest 3 values of 4 fair dice.

Tags: statistics

I used brute force to calculate the Mean and Standard Deviation of the sum of the highest 3 values of 4 fair dice.

$\mu=12.2445987654321, \sigma=2.8468444453115$

And plot a graph from the data:

[image]

This graph looks awfully like the bell curve of Normal Distribution.

So I went to [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/) to check it up, but found out that the data doesn't match.

[image]

Which should be $148$ when $x=11$.

And when I come back and take a closer inspection on the graph, it does look a little bit "skewed".

So, if it's not Normal Distribution, what is it and how do I calculate it?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You have the distribution already, just from the raw values.  If you like you can compute the probability that the minimum value of the four dice is $k$ and then compute the distribution of the sum of the other values (knowing that they are all $≥k$).  Not sure that's all that much easier than the brute force method you used.

Comment: Note that your sum is the sum of all four dice minus the minimum roll.  That helps.  The mean is then the difference of the means, thus $4\times 3.5 - 1.755401235=12.24459877$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks. But is it possible to apply the same rule for calculating Standard Deviation?

Comment: Well, that's always harder.  You could do it if you knew the correlation between the sum of the four and the minimum, but that requires some computation along the lines sketched in my first comment.  I don't see an easy way to do it (which, of course, doesn't mean there isn't one).

Comment: @lulu Could you please be so kind and teach me how to do it (as an answer)? I would like to learn it even if it's "not easy". Much appreciated!

Comment: I tried to push my sketched method through, but it is too messy.  somewhat surprisingly, it is easier if you have a lot of dice.  In that case, the minimum is "sure" to be $1$ so the sum of the top $n-1$ is just the total sum minus $1$, making the variances equal.  But for modest $n$, like $n=4$, I strongly advise simulation (as you have done).  I'll think about it throughout the day and post again if I come up with anything useful.

Comment: @lulu OK, thank you very very much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**Comment.** There are some difficulties here. A simulation will
not give an exact answer, but may be helpful.

- The distribution of the mean
  of the largest three faces is highly discrete, while
  the curves in the Question seem to be for continuous
  distributions.
- There are only 16 possible values for the mean. Presumably, a brute-force
  for method would find the probability of each possible value.
- If the four faces seen in four rolls are $2, 2, 3, 6,$
  then we need to be clear that we are summing $2, 3, 6,$
  even though there is a tie for smallest.

A simulation of a million 4-roll experiment should
find the mean of each distribution correct to 3 or 4 significant digits. The result for the mean agrees
within that margin of error.

```
set.seed(2022)
a = replicate(10^6, sum( sort( sample(1:6, 4, rep=T) )[2:4] ) )
mean(a)
[1] 12.24748   # aprx dist'n mean
2*sd(a)/1000
[1] 0.0056942  # aprx 95% margin is simulation error
length(unique(a))
[1] 16

hist(a, prob=T, col="skyblue2")
 abline(v = mean(a), col="red")
```

[image]

*Note:* This comment does not include the distribution
of the SD.